# bash scripting: how to store the source code file's name in a variable?

Tags: file, bash, scripting

I want the name of the file where the code is written

for example if the script is written in a file called "name.sh"

then i want to have a variable for example

var=name.sh

where var will hold the file's name

but suppose that i don't know the name of the file, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basename.

basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames

> var=$(basename $0)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the bash builtin variable `$0` for this.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo This script file is named `basename $0`
```

If you want to store it in another variable, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

THESCRIPT=$0

echo This script file is named $THESCRIPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want either `$0` or `$_`, which contain the name of the current script. See here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_04

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$0` which is equivalent argv[0] in some other programming languages.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $1
```

If you run the bash script above with `$ sh file.sh one two` you would get the following output.

```
test.sh
one
two
```